# Live Agent Supervisor alert

Tags: liveagent

Our requirement is to provide an alert message for Supervisors in Live Agent when agent is not responding to a customer for specific period of time. Is there any standard or customized way to this ?

So far we are able to show alerts to agents and customers but not supervisors.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the omni console event `lightning:omniChannelWorkDeclined` when the agent is declining the work and notify the manager(user.manager) via email or SF alerts

- [Salesforce Console Developer Guide: lightning:omniChannelWorkDeclined](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_events_omnichannelworkdeclined.htm)

You can use the below winter'19 feature to monitor the work declined event from the console.

- [Salesforce Winter ’19 Release Notes: Use Background Utility Items to Add Functionality to a Lightning App](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_console_background_utility_items.htm)